# Radio buttons and checkboxes grouped together MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox, radio-button

I'm trying to find an MVC (razor) solution where I can use radio buttons and checkboxes together.

Say there are 2 `radiobuttons` labelled: *All people* and *Family Members*.

If you select the "Family Members" `radio button`, 3 `checkboxes` should be enabled: "Employee", "Spouse", "Dependant(s)"

The questions are:

- How to group a radio button to 3 checkboxes?
- How to enable the
  checkboxes when the related radio button is selected?

Comment: You don't have to "group" them per say. If your question is about how to enable the checkboxes/make them visible, you can use jQuery selectors to find all checkboxes in the UL that is directly after the radio button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could do the following:

```
 <ul>
      <li><input type="radio">All People</input></li>
      <li>
          <input type="radio" class="toggle-family">Family Members</input>
          <ul class="member-selection hide">
              <li><input type="checkbox">Employee</input></li>
              ...
          </ul>
      </li>
 </ul>
```

Then in your javascript you could do the following:

```
 $(function() {
      $('.toggle-family').change(function() {
         if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
             $('.member-selection').removeClass('hide');
         } else {
             $('.member-selection').addClass('hide');
         }
      });
 });
```

Then you would need to just define a css class called "hide" and set it display attribute to none.  This is just an idea to get you started, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. That did, in fact, point me in the right direction. ASP.NET, web forms made it so I didn't have to worry about all of these "gory" implementation details.

Comment: They only seem "gory" now...but believe me you will grow to appreciate the control and freedom that you get with working with the pure html and "implementation details".