# How to add a group of radio buttons in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have something like a survey and want users to select one option from a set of answers to a certain question. Here is an example of what i am talking about.

[radio buttons](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-zCPU8bmXjQ0/T8dNzJP31MI/AAAAAAAAAE0/3CUjjaWdn_0/s663/Example.PNG)[1]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497629/radio-buttons-and-checkboxes-grouped-together-mvc  
Does this help ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should help you if you are using html helper in your code:

```
 @Html.RadioButton("rbGrp", "1", true )<label>Option 1</label>
 @Html.RadioButton("rbGrp", "2", false )<label>Option 2</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set group name in input type radio

```
    <input type="radio" name='group1' value="Milk"> Milk 

    <input type="radio" name='group1' value="Butter"> Butter
```